# How to display 3 months one by one in fullcalendar using React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using React components of FullCalendar.io for all my calendar use cases. Is there any way to display 3 months at a time one below the another?

I tried the below code but it didn't work.

```
<FullCalendar 
           plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin , timeGridPlugin]}
           selectable
           headerToolbar={{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
          }}
           duration='3'
           editable={true}
           events = {events}
           select = {onSlotSelect}   
       />
```

This displays only one month. Is there any attribute that will help in displaying three months in one go?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/470) for this request (since 2015...). So the initial answer is no, is not possible to show 3 months.

Anyway someone tries to find a workaround to show more than one month (like [this](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/470#issuecomment-618726507) one).